# Can I automate a snapshot of an Amazon Lightsail instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, amazon-lightsail

I have just set up an instance of a WordPress site on Amazon Lightsail.

I'm looking for a backup solution.

The option to create a snapshot of the instance is there and works fine, but I see in the control panel that each snapshot takes 30GB and "Total snapshot data Snapshots are billed monthly per GB".

Is it feasible to do a daily snapshot without costing a bundle?

Or would it be better just to copy the whole WordPress directory to another directory or a S3 bucket on a daily basis?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to automate the creating snapshots of an Amazon Lightsail instance. Amazon has the CLI tool for all services including Lightsail. You can use it for automation or the AWS SDK tools for different programming languages.

If you want to create your own script you can take a look at these links

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lightsail/create-instance-snapshot.html?highlight=lightsail

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lightsail.html

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/

I also created a script for the AWS Lambda NodeJS to automate the process using AWS SDK. See the instructions and adjust it for your needs.

https://github.com/vidanov/lambda-nodejs-lightsail-backup

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer should contain the solution, [not just a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). If it's too extensive, at least write an outline _how_ the linked content solves the problem. Be aware that [answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I used this as a base for my use case, thank you @AlexeyVidanov. One thing that needs to be very stressed is that the deletion of old snapshots is over ALL Lightsail snapshots of ALL instances. I made a change on my side to only do it to the instance that we care about: https://gist.github.com/minac/165cfe8a98f46730a42f22e33b1834e1

Comment: Thank you, @migueldavid ! I updated the function in the GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **you should use snapshots** rather than copying files. It is always fiddly to recreate a computer with only some of the files and it is easy to miss some important files (eg web server configuration).

Assuming that an Amazon Lightsail snapshots are the same as EBS snapshots (which would be a pretty safe assumption):

- Snapshots only consume space for ***used* blocks of the disk**
- Snapshots are **incremental**, only taking a copy of blocks that have been added or modified since a previous snapshot
- Storage is charged on a **pro-rata basis**, so if it is only stored for 7 days, it would only be charged 7/30 of the cost (7 days divided by 30 days).

To reduce costs, you could take a snapshot each day and only **keep the last *n* snapshots** (eg the last 5 snapshots). You would need to code this yourself but it would be quite simple. (See [example for Amazon EBS volumes](http://codegist.net/snippet/python/snapshotterpy_nguyendangminh_python),
 but Lightsail would involve different API calls.)

Answer (score 0):

For not so technical people like me, **AWS now provides automatic snapshot for last 7 days**.

This can be **easily enabled via console in few simple steps**.

Here is the detailed article.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-lightsail-now-provides-automatic-snapshots/

*which reads*

> Amazon Lightsail now supports automatic snapshots, allowing you to
>   schedule daily snapshots of your Lightsail Linux/Unix instances.
>
> With automatic snapshots, Lightsail will automatically take a daily
>   snapshot for you at a time you specify, eliminating the need to take
>   snapshots manually. Lightsail keeps the seven most recent snapshots,
>   so you can rest easy knowing that you’ll have a full weeks’ worth of
>   snapshot history. Snapshots can be used to restore your instance to a
>   previous state and to create multiple new instances that are replicas
>   of the original instance.
>
> Enabling the feature is free; you only pay for the storage of your
>   snapshots on Lightsail ($0.05 USD per GB per month). Although
>   Lightsail retains your seven most recent automatic snapshots, you can
>   choose to keep specific automatic snapshots as long as you wish or
>   continue to take manual snapshots of the instance (storage for manual
>   snapshots is charged at the same rate, $0.05 USD per GB per month).
>   Moreover, **Lightsail optimizes your snapshot storage so that for each
>   consecutive snapshot, you’re charged only for the data that’s changed
>   from the previous one.**
>
> You can enable automatic snapshots using the Lightsail console or API
>   in all regions where Lightsail is available. To learn more about
>   automatic snapshots on Lightsail, click the link below.
>
> https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-configuring-automatic-snapshots

**Here is how to do it**

- Sign in to the Lightsail console.
- On the Lightsail home page, choose the Instances tab.
- Choose the name of the instance for which you want to enable or disable automatic snapshots.
- On the instance management page, choose the Snapshots tab.
- Under the Automatic snapshots section, choose the toggle to enable it. Likewise, choose the toggle to disable it if it's enabled.
- At the prompt, choose Yes, enable to enable automatic snapshots, or Yes, disable to disable the feature.
  The automatic snapshot is enabled or disabled after a few moments.